# Bases of linear spaces vs topological linear spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

By definition, the basis of a linear space $V$ is a subset $S$ of $V$ that finitely spans $V$.

Consider the linear space $V_2$ over $F_2$ consisting of sequences of $\{0, 1\}$, equipped with the topology of $m=\sum_1^{\infty}(a_i2^{-i})$ (ignore the equivalence between the sequence ending with all $1$ and that with all $0$).

We usually take the set $B$ consisting of vectors with exactly one $1$ as the basis. However, this "basis" $B$ obviously doesn't finitely span $V_2$. $V_2$ is the completion of $B$.

Does this mean that we have another definition of basis for topological linear space that allows "finitely spans" to be replaced to "finitely or infinitely spans"?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What are $a_i$? Also, please, rewrite the sum in the definition of $m$ using mathjax, currently, I don't know what you are summing over and what the summation index is.

Comment: It is common to use such an alternate type of basis in certain contexts.  That is, we allow for infinite linear combinations when considering a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) as opposed to a [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Hamel_basis).

Comment: What is $m$ exactly? I'm guessing that you're trying to define neighbourhoods of the origin, but it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read up something about *[Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space)* in which you have the concept of an *orthonormal basis*. A set $S$ is a basis for a Hilbert space $H$ if the **closure** of the span of $S$ is equal to $H$. This means that instead of simply finite sums, you can also have some vectors that can be written as infinite sums of basis vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The concept can be readily extended to any topological vector space (linear space equipped with a topology, in which the closure can be defined). Then, what confused me was: a basis in a topological vector space is not necessary a basis of the underlying linear space. Is this correct?

Comment: @MilesZhou You're welcome. Remember, if the answer was what you needed, you can also upvote or/and accept it.